# Characters on rings of residue classes modulo polynomials over finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, analytic-number-theory, characters, exponential-sum, function-fields

First recall the following orthogonality relation on $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Fix $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n \neq 0$. For $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, let $e(r) := e^{2 \pi i r}$. Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then one can show that
$$
\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{h=0}^{n-1}e\left(h\dfrac{x}{n}\right) = \begin{cases}
                                      1 & \mbox{ if } n \mid x;\\
                                      0 & \mbox{ otherwise.}
                                      \end{cases}
$$

I wonder what is the analogue for polynomials over finite fields. How do the characters here look like? Note that $e(x)$ was defined on $\mathbb{Q}$ so that we have that orthogonality. So I'm guessing the characters on $F[x]/gF[x]$, for $F$ a finite field and $g \in F[x]\setminus\{0\}$,
should be defined on the function field $F(x)$. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to check out Section 3 of Keith Conrad's notes on characters of finite abelian groups:  http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/charthy.pdf

Comment: So essentially, find generators of your finite abelian group $G$.  Pick a $|G|$th root of unity to send each generator to.  That will define a character on the group.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to know whether we could have a more explicit character on $F[x]/g F[x]$. For instance, suppose you have a function $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ and you're interested in an estimate of $S = \#\{1 \leq m \leq N \ : \  m \equiv a \pmod{b}, \ f(m) \equiv c \pmod{k}  \}$ for some $a,b,c,k \in \mathbb{Z}$ fixed. One could write $S = \sum_{m=1}^N \dfrac{1}{b} \sum_{h=0}^{b-1} e(\frac{h(m-a)}{b})\frac{1}{k}\sum_{s = 0}^{k-1} e(\frac{s( f(m) -c   )   }{k})$.

Comment: Now one of the beauties of the $x \mapsto e(x)$ function is that it can combine the two characters modulo $b,k$ respectively and hence can write $S = \frac{1}{bk} \sum_{h=0}^{b-1}e(ha/b) \sum_{s = 0}^{k-1}e(-sc/k)\sum_{m=1}^N e(sf(m)/k - hm/b)$. Note the last summation with summand $e(sf(m)/k - hm/b)$. I'm interested in an analogue for this in $F[x]$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @JohnM: You have the right idea, but you need to exercise a bit more care. A generator $g$ needs to be mapped to a root of unity of order $\operatorname{ord}_G(g)$. If $G$ is not cyclic (which is the case here), then the orders of the elements are strictly less than $|G|$.

Comment: $\chi_{a,n}(k) = e^{2 i \pi a k /n}$ is a character of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)$ right. But I don't get the rest. You want to generalize it to what group ? $G = (F[x]/(g(x)),+) $ where $F$ is a finite field and $g(x)$ a polynomial ? doesn't $G$ have a much simpler representation ?

Comment: And finding the characters of an abelian group is really not complicated, a character $\chi_G$ of $G = A \times B$ will decompose as $\chi_A \chi_B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this exactly what you are looking for, but here comes anyway.

---

The additive group of $F[x]$, $F=\Bbb{F}_q$, $q=p^n$ is just an infinite dimensional vector space over the prime field $\Bbb{F}_p$. Therefore the values of all characters are $p$th complex roots of unity.

A popular (standard?) description the characters of the additive group $(F,+)$ is the following. Let $tr:F\to\Bbb{F}_p$ be the trace map
$$
tr(x)=x+x^p+x^{p^2}+\cdots+x^{p^{n-1}}.
$$
The trace is a non-trivial homomorphism from $(F,+)$ to $(\Bbb{F}_p,+)$, and we get a character of $(F,+)$ by composing it with the obvious character $e:\Bbb{F}_p\to\Bbb{C}^*$ given by $e(x)=e^{2\pi i x/p}$.

From all of the above it follows that for any $a\in F$ we get a character $\chi_a$ of $(F,+)$ from the recipe
$$
\chi_a(x):=e(tr(ax)).
$$
It is not hard to show that the characters $\chi_a$ are distinct for distinct choices of $a$, and that we get all the characters of $(F,+)$ in this way.

As a more or less immediate corollary of this we get all the characters of the additive group of $F[x]$ from the following recipe. Select an arbitrary sequence
$\vec{a}=(a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ of elements of $F$. A character $\chi_{\vec{a}}$ of $F[x]$ associated with this sequence is the mapping
$
\chi_{\vec{a}}:F[x]\to\Bbb{C}
$
defined by
$$
\chi_{\vec{a}}(c_0+c_1x+\cdots +c_mx^m):=e\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m}tr(a_jc_j)\right)
$$
for all polynomials $c(x)=\sum_{j=0}^mc_jx^j\in F[x]$, $m$ an arbitrary natural number.

When we consider the quotient ring $F[x]/\langle g(x)\rangle$ nothing much changes. We only need to make sure that we get a well-defined mapping. This means that we can only consider vectors $\vec{a}$ such that $\chi_{\vec{a}}(bx^jg(x))=1$ for all integers $j\ge0$ and all $b\in F$. What this means is that if $m=\deg g(x)$, then we can choose $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{m-1}$ any which way we want, but these then determine a unique choice of $a_m, a_{m+1},\ldots$.

The additive group of the quotient ring $F[x]/\langle g(x)\rangle$ is, after all, isomorphic to that of the vector space $F^m$, so we expect the description of the characters to be given in terms of $m$ constants of $F$ as well. All in line with the fact that the character group of a finite abelian group is isomorphic to the group itself. The isomorphism is not natural in any way, and that is reflected in the somewhat arbitrary use of the trace function (any non-trivial homomorphism of additive groups could serve its role equally well).

Comment: Thanks very much Jyrki. Would you know any paper or book in literature where such characters modulo polynomials have been used before? Specifically, I'm interested in estimating numbers of the following form:

Comment: $\#\left\{ f \in F[x] \ : \ \deg(f) \leq N \ : \ f \equiv h \pmod{g}, \ S(f) = c\right\}$, where $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $h \in F[x]$ and $c \in F$ are fixed, while $S : \mathbb{F}[x] \to F$ is some fixed function. My hope is that I will be able to use similar tools as on $\mathbb{Z}$; see one of the comments above. Thank you very much!

Comment: There are other questions that come to mind. For instance, over $\mathbb{Z}$, partial geometric sum such as $\sum_{j=0}^s e(j \gamma)$, with $\gamma $ fixed, has a well-known upper bound for its modulus. However, what type of upper bound should we expect for something like $|\sum_{c \in F} \psi(cx^k)|$, where $\psi$ is a non-trivial additive character on $F[x]$? I understand characters on $F$, but I'm completely new to characters on function fields or $F[x]$

Comment: @user152169: The polynomials of the form $cx^k$ form an additive subgroup of $F[x]$, so that sum is either zero or trivial, all depending on whether the parameter $a_k$ vanishes or not.

Comment: @user152169:  You may find some helpful ideas in Chapter 11 of Iwaniec and Kowalski.

Comment: @user152169: I'm not too well versed in number theory, but if you are interested in studying the analogy between the rings $\Bbb{Z}$ and $F[x]$ I really, really recommend [Michael Rosen's book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953359?token=prtst0416p2).